# How CNN model predict raw (big) images?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning

what I am trying to do is detect hair cracks from surface of infrastructures such as bridges and pavements, etc.

As far as I know, it would be segmentation problem, I am thinking about using U-net as a back-bone.
However, dataset I found from google search is 125X125 and I want to predict raw images size of 4500x4700 using a trained model.
My question is how to implement the raw (big) image on CNN model that has been trained small size images.

Thanks

Comment: One thing you can do is use the U-net on 125x125 patches of the image. Or resize the image to 125x125.

Comment: I am thinking about using a sliding window to big images, is there any example code that I refer to?